# '+' is deprecated: Mixed-type addition is deprecated in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, swift3, addition

When I'm directly adding an integer value(i.e: 1,2,3,etc) with another integer variable

```
let arr:Array = ["One","Two"]
var valueT:Int64 = 0
value = arr.count + 1 //in this line
```

I get the following warning:

```
'+' is deprecated: Mixed-type addition is deprecated. Please use explicit type conversion.
```

**I fixed it the warning with this**:

```
value = Int64(value + 1)
```

Though **it is fixed** but I wanna know why its called **Mixed-type addition** as I didn't use **++** . Also is there a better way to fix the warning in swift 3.1?

Update:

The following image is the proof of warning. I'm using Xcode Version 8.3 (8E162).

[image]

`allROR` is an array here.

Comment: `1` is `Int`, not `Int64`.

Comment: Your code compiles without warnings in my Xcode 8.3.2.

Comment: @JuicyFruit: Not quite. `1` is an *integer literal* and can be `Int` or `Int64` (or `Double` or ...) depending on the context.

Comment: @MartinR Have you checked this one https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/6603/files

Comment: @NiravD:  I vaguely remember a problem where a integer literal was mistaken as `Int64.Stride` which is `Int`. However, I cannot reproduce the problem with above code. Can you?

Comment: @MartinR You are right I have tried and cannot reproduce the problem with above code I have also tried on http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59140e5a5ec5ef2986a89c63 and there is still no warning

Comment: @MartinR : I also don't have warnings. But I just wanna know is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Poles: In your question you claim that there is a compiler warning. I cannot reproduce that, and now you say that you don't have warnings. So what do you want to fix? What "better way" are you asking for if there is no problem?

Comment: @MartinR : `let result = value + 1` this line gives me warning. After that I fixed it with `let result = Int64(value + 1)`. So I just wanted to know if there is any other way we can fix the warning?

Comment: @Poles: And I do not get that warning for `let result = value + 1`. Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: @MartinR : Xcode 8.3

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, did it without knowing the actual problem. Actually what you will loose if you downvoted a question or answer. Its just a click :(

Comment: @Poles Please copy and paste a [mcve] into your question. As others have pointed out, the first example you give does not reproduce the warning.

Comment: @Hamish : I have the proof as I uploaded the image.

Comment: @Poles A screenshot is not too helpful, as others cannot easily reproduce it, and the link may die over time. Copying and pasting a MCVE into your question allows us to easily reproduce the problem without having to make assumptions about the code in your screenshot (for example, we don't know how `allROR` is declared).

Comment: @Poles The edit you made to your first example still doesn't manifest the warning. You need to add an `Int` with an integer literal, and then assign the result to an `Int64` to reproduce.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit:** To generate the error with your code it should be like

```
let value = 5
let result: Int64 = value + 1
```

Now you get the warning

> '+' is deprecated: Mixed-type addition is deprecated. Please use explicit type conversion.

But it is looks like warning is misleading, as of both `value` and `1` is of type `Int` so its summation also `Int` so you need to simply convert the result  to `Int64` and it is what you doing and that is perfectly ok.

```
let result: Int64 = Int64(value + 1)
```

Comment: This does not explain the problem. *Which* `+` is deprecated? *Why* do you have to cast the integer literal explicitly? – Can you reproduce the problem with the code from the question?

Comment: @MartinR Edited answer to specify problem is not producing in Xcode 8.3.2

Comment: @NiravD : Why adding +1 is declared as **Mixed-type addition**?

Comment: @Poles Don't get you what do you mean by `+1 is declared as Mixed-type` ?

Comment: deprecated Mixed-type addition means you can't add **Int64** with **Int**...right?

Comment: @Poles Yes but only updated image not the code that you have added

Comment: @Poles These lines of code `var value:Int64 = 5

value = value + 1 //in this line` is not producing any warning I have show you the link also check that once again https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59140e5a5ec5ef2986a89c63

Comment: @Poles Have you check my answer I have told you that error is misleading and the conversion you are doing is perfect and its need to be that way

Comment: Ok. Understood.

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer this part: ***why its called Mixed-type addition***

With the simplified example by Nirav D:

```
let value = 5
let result: Int64 = value + 1
```

You can Command-click on `+` and see the generated interface of `Collection`:
(After *Indexing* has finished, of course.)

> ```
> @available(swift, deprecated: 3.0, obsoleted: 4.0, message: "Mixed-type addition is deprecated. Please use explicit type conversion.")
> public func +<T>(lhs: T.Stride, rhs: T) -> T where T : SignedInteger
> ```

So, in the code example above, the type of `1` is inferred as `Int64`, and as `Int64.Stride == Int`, the operation `value + 1` matches the signature `func +<T>(lhs: T.Stride, rhs: T) -> T where T : SignedInteger`.

This deprecation is included in the revised version of SE-0104 [Protocol-oriented integers](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md), this part:

> - Standard Library no longer provides + and - operators for Strideable types.
>
>   They were problematic, as one could have written mixed-type code like
>     let x: Int64 = 42; x += (1 as Int), which would compile, but
>     shouldn't. Besides, since the Stride of an unsigned type is signed,
>     Standard Library had to implement a hack to make code like let x: UInt
>     = 42; x += (1 as Int) ambiguous. These operators were only necessary because they made advancing collection indices convenient, which is no
>     longer the case since the introduction of the new indexing model in
>     Swift 3.

As you already have seen, you can avoid this warning in many ways.

Answer (score 2):

Data type is different that is why it is showing an error

you need to make both variable and constant of same data type

for e.g.

```
let result = value + Int64(1) //in this line
```

Answer (score 1):

OK

```
var arr = [String]()
var i: Int64 = 0
if arr.count == 0 {
    i = 1
} else {
    i = arr.count + 1
}
```

gives as a warning '+' is deprecated: Mixed-type addition is deprecated. Please use explicit type conversion.

The reason is, that **arr.count and i has different types**. And this warning is right. **It has nothing with the integer literal 1**

this snippet gives you the warning too

```
var arr = [String]()
var i: Int64 = 0
if arr.count == 0 {
    i = 1
} else {
    i = 1
    i += arr.count // here is the warning now
}
```

this will not compile, even though it looks very similar

```
var arr = [String]()
var i: Int64 = 0
if arr.count == 0 {
    i = 1
} else {
    let tmp = arr.count + 1
    i = tmp
}
```

I hope we get an error message when we compose all of these snippets in the future release.

Comment: Now. That is what I was talking about.

Comment: @Poles: Which means that your initial example `let result = value + 1` was wrong. The problem occurs because the result is assigned to a variable of type `Int64`, and that was not apparent from your question.