# Using variable as lower bound for arc4random - explicit type/strideable?

Tags: ios, swift4, swift4.1

)

I have updated a "Workout Object" to have both a minimum and maximum number of reps.

When I've been hardcoding the lower bound in a playground, I've been using :

```
let numberOfExercises = Int(arc4random_uniform(4) + 3)
```

When I try to use variables in a function/with a class object I get an error of "+'is unavailable: Please use explicit type conversions or Strideable methods for mixed-type arithmetics" e.g. here ...

```
class ExerciseGeneratorObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var minReps = 0
    @objc dynamic var maxReps = 0    

    convenience init(name: String, minReps: Int, maxReps: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.minReps = minReps
        self.maxReps = maxReps
    }

    func generateExercise() -> WorkoutExercise {
        return WorkoutExercise(
            name: name,
//get error on this line...
            reps: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxReps))+minReps)
        )
    }
}
```

There is an answer here [+ is unavailable: Please use explicit type conversions or Strideable methods for mixed-type arithmetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839346/is-unavailable-please-use-explicit-type-conversions-or-strideable-methods-for) but that method is already using  so don't see how it's applicable here.

Also here ['+' is deprecated: Mixed-type addition is deprecated in Swift 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907984/is-deprecated-mixed-type-addition-is-deprecated-in-swift-3-1) but again think this is a different problem

Comment: use this `Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxReps)))+minReps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> '+' is unavailable: Please use explicit type conversions or Strideable methods for mixed-type arithmetics.

Example:

```
let a: UInt32 = 4
let b = 3

let result = a + b //error
```

Basically means you can't add **mixed-types**.

---

In your case when you do `arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxReps)) + minReps`, `arc4random_uniform()` returns a `UInt32` which cannot be added to `minReps` because that's an `Int`.

#### Solution:

Update your parenthesis:

```
let numberOfExercises = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxReps))) + minReps
```

Here `Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxReps)))` gives an `Int` that we can add to the `minReps` `Int`.

---

BTW, the following works out-of-the-box:

```
let numberOfExercises = Int(arc4random_uniform(4) + 3)
```

Because of Swift's automatic type inference. Basically it just went ahead with `UInt32` without bothering you. That is... until you give it explicit mixed types.

Comment: This worked - at first it didn't but realise i was calling it incorrectly!

Comment: @nc14 Good to know! Happy coding :)